# How to properly convert the Last-Modified header from an HTTP response to an NSDate on iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am looking for a fully working solution, one that works with:

- any iOS locale or timezone
- any/most HTTP servers
- Xcode 4.0.2 [(see why)](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/32501-datefromstring-works-simulator-not-device.html)

Current broken code:

```
 NSString lastModifiedString = @"Mon, 06 Jun 2011 12:47:05 GMT";
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
 //df.dateFormat = @"EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'";
 df.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
 df.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];  
 df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];  
 NSDate date = [df dateFromString:lastModifiedString];
```

I assumed that `Last-Modified` is supposed to use the same format like other date fields in HTTP spec, meaning to use RFC-1123 / RFC-822

Resources:

- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html HTTP 1.1
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: @karim this was long time ago and solved (i don't remember exactly how) but I do not see the point on your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It helps me. I was just comparing with "Last-Modified" header and the date formatter string (pasting the header here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing wrong is that you're missing asterisks in-between `NSString` and `lastModifiedString`, and also between `NSDate` and `date`.  Once you put those in, this code works for me.